# ERROR: Command erroded out with exit status 3221226505 (см. скриншот)

Tags: cmd

Я пытался установить библиотеку pyautogui через командную строку, но выскакивает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd: окей, я тупой, ошибка исправлена